# differentiation of an expression in statistics

Tags: statistics, derivatives, summation

I have a problem to differentiate this expression w.r.t. t:

$$\theta_0(1-t)^2+\sum_{x=2}^\infty\theta_0^{x-2}(1-\theta_0)^2(x-2)^2t^2$$

where the result should be

$$t=[1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\theta_0^{k-1}k^2(1-\theta_0)^2]^{-1}$$
esp. I do not understand why $k^2$ has replaced $t^2$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no replacement of $t$ by $k$.

We have some function of $t$, call it

$$\begin{align}
S(t) &= \theta_0 (1 - t)^2 + \sum_{x=2}^\infty \theta_0^{x-2} (1-\theta_0)^2 (x-2)^2 t^2 \\
&= \theta_0 (1-t)^2 + t^2 \sum_{x=2}^\infty \theta_0^{x-2} (1-\theta_0)^2 (x-2)^2. \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Notice how the $t^2$ term factors out of the sum.  Let us define
$$\begin{align}
K &= \sum_{x=2}^\infty \theta_0^{x-2} (1-\theta_0)^2 (x-2)^2 \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \theta_0^k (1 - \theta_0)^2 k^2 \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \theta_0^k (1 - \theta_0)^2 k^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
All we have done in $(2)$ is let $k = x-2$, and then recognize that the first term in this sum is zero, since $k^2 = 0$ when $k = 0$.  So now
$$S(t) = \theta_0 (1 - t)^2 + K t^2. \tag{3}$$
We want to compute the critical point(s) of $S$ with respect to $t$; i.e., we want to find $t$ such that
$$0 = \frac{dS}{dt} = -2\theta_0(1-t) + 2K t = 2(K+\theta_0)t - 2\theta_0. \tag{4}$$
It follows that
$$t = \frac{\theta_0}{K + \theta_0} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{K}{\theta_0}} = \left(1 + \frac{K}{\theta_0}\right)^{-1}. \tag{5}$$
is such a critical point.  Now substitute back $K$:

$$\begin{align}
t &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{\theta_0} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \theta_0^k (1-\theta_0)^2 k^2 \right)^{-1} \\
&=\left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \theta_0^{k-1} (1-\theta_0)^2 k^2 \right)^{-1} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

as claimed.